# setting the target version to 1.8 still produce the class files with major version 52

Tags: ant, java-8, javac, javap

I am trying to compile my java source code to target 1.8. I have set the following in the javac target.

Ant version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
Java version: 1.8

```
<target name="compile" depends="prepare">
    <echo>Mayuran</echo>
    <echo>Ant version: ${ant.version}</echo>
    <echo>java version: ${ant.java.version}</echo>
    <javac srcdir="${buildpath.src}" source="1.8" target="1.8" destdir="${buildpath.out}" classpathref="build.classpath" debug="${build-classes.debugOption}" includeantruntime="${build.inclAntRTOption}"/>
</target>
```

But when i check the generated class file using the javap tool, it is still showing the class files is major 52(JDK 7)

```
javap -classpath . -verbose com.mayuran.Test
```

Does anyone has idea why it is happening?

Regards,
Mayuran

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong to my eyes. Try adding `verbose="yes"` to your `javac` task to see if that reveals anything else. Also, ensure the `.class` file is in `destdir` and has been freshly built by deleting prior to Ant execution.

Comment: Thanks for input, I have verified that class files are newly created. Still not able to figure it  out. going to try with verbose option

Comment: Sorry my bad, Major version 52 is JDK 8 already.

Comment: Then you can remove your question